# qz like function in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matlab

MATLAB has the function [`qz()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qz.html) such that `[AA, BB, Q, Z, V, W] = qz(A, B)` produces matrices `V` and `W` whose columns are generalized eigenvectors. This function gives the right and left eigenvectors. I didn't find a similar function in *Mathematica*. Does it exist?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the built-ins `Eigensystem`, `Eigenvalues`, or `Eigenvectors` can do this. See the documentation.

Comment: This [page](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/lapack_analysis/lapack.htm) has maping of some matlab functions to Mathematica, including `qz`. But Matlab `qz` returns number of values. So may be there is some functionality not there. But f you have specific example you want to see it in Matlab, you can provide one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As already hinted, *Mathematica* is perfectly capable of computing the eigensystem of a pencil. However, none of the commenters gave the function that is the closest to the functionality of MATLAB's `qz()`, and that is *Mathematica*'s `SchurDecomposition[]`.

Briefly put, when given a pencil (as a list of two square matrices of the same dimensions), `SchurDecomposition[]` will return the generalized Schur decomposition (apparently termed the "QZ decomposition" in some circles). More concretely, given a pencil $(\mathbf A,\mathbf B)$, `SchurDecomposition[]` will return a similar (i.e., same eigenvalues) pencil $(\mathbf T,\mathbf U)$, where  $\mathbf T$ and $\mathbf U$ are quasitriangular matrices, and are related to $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ as $\mathbf Q\mathbf T\mathbf Z^\top=\mathbf A$, and $\mathbf Q\mathbf U\mathbf Z^\top=\mathbf B$, where $\mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf Z$ are orthogonal matrices. (For complex matrices, replace transpose with conjugate transpose, quasitriangular with triangular, and orthogonal with unitary.)

(If you are reading [Golub and Van Loan](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=5U-l8U3P-VUC&pg=PT395), note that my convention is slightly different from theirs.)

If the resulting pencil is triangular, the eigenvalues of the pencil can be obtained as the ratio of the diagonal elements of $\mathbf T$ and $\mathbf U$. Zero diagonal elements in $\mathbf U$ correspond to *infinite* eigenvalues of the pencil.

Let's look first at what MATLAB does:

```matlab
A = [3 2 1; 2 3 1; 5 1 2];

B = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

[at, bt, q, z] = qz(A, B)

at =

   -2.1394    6.0702    2.8152
         0    0.8982    1.8737
         0         0   -2.0817


bt =

    1.9287   14.3282    2.2505
         0    8.2195    1.8326
         0         0         0


q =

   -0.6272   -0.5758   -0.5244
    0.6633   -0.0420   -0.7472
    0.4082   -0.8165    0.4082


z =

    0.4729   -0.4012   -0.7845
    0.3630   -0.7226    0.5883
   -0.8029   -0.5630   -0.1961
```

Here is the *Mathematica* equivalent:

```
amat = N[{{3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1}, {5, 1, 2}}];
bmat = N[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}];

MatrixForm /@ ({q, at, z, bt} = SchurDecomposition[{amat, bmat}])
```

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
 -0.627226 & 0.663265 & 0.408248 \\
 -0.575823 & -0.0419709 & -0.816497 \\
 -0.524419 & -0.747207 & 0.408248 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 -2.13941 & 6.07017 & -2.81516 \\
 0. & 0.898164 & -1.87371 \\
 0. & 0. & 2.08167 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 0.47294 & -0.401178 & 0.784465 \\
 0.362966 & -0.722566 & -0.588348 \\
 -0.802859 & -0.562988 & 0.196116 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 1.92866 & 14.3282 & -2.25052 \\
 0. & 8.21954 & -1.83255 \\
 0. & 0. & 0. \\
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Note the similarities and differences in the output. For MATLAB, we have the relations `q.' * at * z.' == A` and `q.' * bt * z.' == B`, while for *Mathematica*, we have `q.at.Transpose[z] == amat` and `q.bt.Transpose[z] == bmat`.

---

Additionally, MATLAB's `qz()` provides a form where the (right and left) eigenvectors of the given pencil are also produced. In *Mathematica*, `Eigenvectors[]` (and thus `Eigensystem[]` as well) can work on a pencil. Using the same matrices as above in both MATLAB and *Mathematica*:

```matlab
[at, bt, q, z, vl, wl] = qz(A, B)

...

vl =

    0.5891    0.2404   -0.5000
    0.4521   -0.0128    1.0000
   -1.0000   -1.0000   -0.5000


wl =

   -1.0000    1.0000    0.5000
    0.2915   -0.7044   -1.0000
    0.1749   -0.4226    0.5000
```

where I had omitted the output of the other four matrices. In *Mathematica*, the equivalent for `vl` is

```
MatrixForm[vecs = Eigenvectors[{amat, bmat}]]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0.408248 & -0.816497 & 0.408248 \\
 0.47294 & 0.362966 & -0.802859 \\
 0.233732 & -0.0124306 & -0.972221 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

It looks a little different from what MATLAB produced, but we can verify that certain properties are satisfied. In MATLAB:

```matlab
adi = diag(diag(at));
bdi = diag(diag(bt));

norm(A * vl * bdi - B * vl * adi)

ans =

   1.3591e-14
```

and in *Mathematica*:

```
amat.Transpose[vecs[[{2, 3, 1}]]].DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[bt]] - 
bmat.Transpose[vecs[[{2, 3, 1}]]].DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[at]]
   7.65362*10^-15
```

(Note that I needed to permute the eigenvectors to agree with the order in the generalized Schur decomposition.)

As for `wl`, that is the set of left eigenvectors for the pencil. Unfortunately, in *Mathematica*, there is no convenient way to get the left eigenvectors, so you have to do a second computation:

```
MatrixForm[lvecs = Eigenvectors[Transpose /@ {amat, bmat}]]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0.408248 & -0.816497 & 0.408248 \\
 -0.946782 & 0.276006 & 0.165603 \\
 -0.772724 & 0.544287 & 0.326572 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Check in MATLAB:

```matlab
norm(bdi * wl.' * A - adi * wl.' * B)

ans =

   1.0668e-14
```

and in *Mathematica*:

```
Norm[DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[bt]].lvecs[[{2, 3, 1}]].amat - 
     DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[at]].lvecs[[{2, 3, 1}]].bmat]
   5.36595*10^-15
```

Comment: Perhaps a naive question, but where does the term *pencil* come from here?

Comment: "Pencil" is actually a [more general term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil), but most conventionally applied to a pair of matrices. It comes from projective geometry; see [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196048).

Comment: @J.M.   Thanks for the sophisticated answer.